# Getting back control of a domain taken by the "Domain Registry of America" scam

Tags: dns

One of my clients ended up getting sucked into the "Domain Registry of America" scam letters that they send out and has now effectively lost the domain to them. My clients name is still the registrant, admin and technical contact but all the other details  - address, phone, email - are for the DRoA. I expect we will not be able to get the domain back because of this. Anyone have any possible solutions other then waiting for the domain to expire?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, this disgusting company is still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your client might possibly want to pursue this with his lawyer. It's possible that DRoA acted fraudelently. No doubt that DRoA has their scam all figured out, so it's unlikely that your client will get his domain back without ponying up some cash, but a nice legal nasty-gram might shake them up a bit.